# Archive 5 random records an hour from a table and also make the weight 1/4th

Tags: mysql, events, datetime, random

I have 2 tables one is `InvoiceFull`  and other is `TestInvoiceFull`.

In my php and mysql based web application 100s of records are being entered into `InvoiceFull` every hour. 
I need to create an event in MySQL to fetch 5 records per hour and 1/4th the weight from `InvoiceFull` and insert these records into `TestInvoiceFull`. TestInvoiceFull is my Archive table.

I have written the query as follows which inserts 1 record per hour but i need 5 records per hour.

```
INSERT INTO TestInvoiceFull (Weight,Status,StatusChangedTime)
SELECT a.Weight/4 AS ApprovedWeight,
       a.Status,
       a.StatusChangedTime
FROM InvoiceFull a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DATE(StatusChangedTime) date, HOUR(StatusChangedTime) hour,
                                        MIN(StatusChangedTime) min_date
   FROM InvoiceFull
   WHERE status='Approved'
   GROUP BY DATE(StatusChangedTime),
            HOUR(StatusChangedTime)) b ON DATE(a.StatusChangedTime) = b.date
AND HOUR(a.StatusChangedTime) = b.hour
AND a.StatusChangedTime = b.min_date;
```

I have selected minimum time in the hour group and thus fetching only 1 row per hour. How can I fetch 5 or in general case N no of records per hour.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are:

1. Randomly chosen records...
2. From the previous hour...
3. Inserted with modifications...
4. **Edit** in ascending order by datetime.

Let's take these one at a time.  To randomly choose five records, you need

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM table
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 5
```

It's not fast but it will work.

Second, you need to pick records with `StatusChangedTime` in the previous hour.  To do that you need a way of getting the beginning of the present hour.

```
STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

does that. It takes the time `NOW()` and changes the minutes and seconds to zero. We can use the same idea to get the beginning of the previous hour:

```
STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

So, let's use those expressions in a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM InvoiceFull a
 WHERE a.StatusChangedTime >= STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND a.StatusChangedTime  < STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

This chooses all the rows starting with the beginning of the previous row, up until *but not including* the beginning of the present hour.

Next, you need to modify one of the columns in your result set. You did that correctly.  If your `Weight` column is a floating-point value, you probably should use `Weight * 0.25` instead of division.

```
INSERT INTO TestInvoiceFull
       (Weight,Status,StatusChangedTime)
SELECT (a.Weight * 0.25) AS ApprovedWeight,
       a.Status,
       a.StatusChangedTime  ...
```

Finally, you want the random five records in order by datetime stamp.  So put your basic `SELECT` query into a subquery ...

```
INSERT INTO TestInvoiceFull
       (Weight,Status,StatusChangedTime)
SELECT *
  FROM (
  SELECT (a.Weight * 0.25) AS ApprovedWeight,
         a.Status,
         a.StatusChangedTime
    FROM InvoiceFull a
   WHERE a.StatusChangedTime >= STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
     AND a.StatusChangedTime  < STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 5
  ) b ORDER BY StatusChangedTime
```

There are your five random records, in date order. Run this sometime in each hour and you'll get your sample of the last hour's records. I've had best results waiting until five or ten minutes past each hour for this stuff, just in case some part of the system is running behind.

Notice that you were misusing `GROUP BY` in the query in your question. `GROUP BY` only helps you if you're using aggregate operations like `SUM()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I need more help. I want to get the random records but these records should be in order of the StatusChangedTime. Like If I have 12 records with time as 18:05:00,   18:09:00,   18:14:00,   18:21:00,   18:33:00,   18:37:00,   18:38:00,   18:39:00,   18:39:08,   18:40:05,   18:40:08,   18:45:00 than i should get following five records 18:05:00,   18:14:00,   18:37:00,   18:38:00,   18:40:05.... Now I am getting random records as 18:38:00,   18:05:00,   18:14:00,   18:40:05,   18:37:00.....

Comment: In my case the MySQL DATE_FORMAT function works fine instead of STR_TO_DATE. The code that I used is <br />`INSERT INTO TestInvoiceFull (Weight,Status,StatusChangedTime) SELECT (a.Weight * 0.25) AS ApprovedWeight, a.Status, a.StatusChangedTime FROM InvoiceFull a WHERE a.StatusChangedTime >= DATE_FORMAT('2014-10-10 17:07:32', '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND a.StatusChangedTime < DATE_FORMAT('2014-10-10 17:07:32', '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5`

Comment: Of course, using `DATE_FORMAT`, you're implicitly typecasting a date string to a `DATETIME` item, then explicitly formatting it back to a string, then implicitly typecasting it back to a `DATETIME` item to use in your comparison. Sure, it works. It's also efficient because it only happens at the beginning of the query.